# Solving the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dt}=e^{t-y}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on the equation 
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=e^{t-y},\qquad y(0) = 1$$

This is what I have tried to get it to its exact solution:
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=e^{t}e^{-y}$$
$$\frac{1}{e^{-y}}dy=e^{t}dt$$
$$e^{y}dy=e^{t}dt$$
$$\int e^{y}dy=\int e^{t}dt$$
$$e^{y}=e^{t}+C $$
$$e^{1}-e^{0}=C <y=1, t=0>$$
$$e^{1}-1=C$$

going back:

$$e^{y}=e^{t}+\ln(e^{1}-1) $$
$$\ln(e^{y})=\ln(e^{t}+e-1) $$
$$y=\ln(e^{t}+e-1)$$

Latex made me see my problem, Thank you for helping if you answered!

Comment: Your line $\ln(e^y)-\ln(e^t) = C$ is wrong. $\ln(a+b)\neq \ln(a)+\ln(b)$...

Comment: The problem is on the eighth step when you take the natural log. You took the natural log of a sum and then the summands. This is wrong

Comment: I would use the initial condition at the stage $e^y=e^t+C$. Put $t=0$. Then $y=1$ so $C=e-1$. So we have $e^y=e^t+e-1$. Now take the ln of both sides.

Comment: slightly, embarrassed... despite, Thank you so much guys! I appreciate it so much. Great tip André, I will keep that in mind!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're fine until you tried to take logarithms of both sides. First, you do not know that $C>0$ initially, so that step may not even make sense. Second, more importantly, it is not true that $\ln(e^y - e^t) = \ln(e^y) - \ln(e^t)$. Instead you should leave $e^t$ on the other side, and do:

$$e^y = e^t + C \\
\ln(e^y) = \ln(e^t + C) \\
y = \ln(e^t + C)$$

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake was where you went:
$$e^{y}-e^{t}=C \implies \ln(e^{y})-\ln(e^{t})=C$$

Instead, you should have:
$$e^{y}-e^{t}=C \implies \ln(e^{y}-e^{t})=C$$

(I would plug in the values for $y$ and $t$ in the RHS of the implication above.  No need to solve further for $C$.)

Answer (score 1):

$e^y = e^t + C$ and since $y(0) = 1$ then $e = 1 + C$ so $C = e - 1$ and therefore $y = \ln{(e^t+e-1)}$